# Big O Understand Quadratic n(n+1)/2 diagram

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, quadratic

Reading DS & Algorithms on Quadratic n(n+1)/2. There are 2 diagrams here Figure 4.1a & 4.1b.

I understand 4.1a diagram but not diagram 4.1b.

I know Figure 4.1b is n/2 (x-axis) multiple (n+1) (y-axis). I don't understand the jaggeet line shown in this figure.

Any help be great.

[image: Quadratic]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Visual representation

It's quite simple really.
You take the last bar from `4(a)` and stick it on the first bar of `4(a)`. That results in the first bar of chart `4(b)`. Then you take the second to last and second bar of chart `4(a)`, stick them on top of each other and you get the second bar for chart `4(b)`. And you can do this for the other bars as well.

That's just a visual representation of the formula so that you can easily see it's `n(n+1)/2`.

### Mathematical idea

When you think of it in more mathematical terms it's also quite logical.

We have `n` summands.

`1 +   2   +   3   +  ...   + (n-3) + (n-2) + (n-1) + n`

Now write the same numbers from `1 to n` beneath this in reversed order so from `n to 1`.

`n + (n-1) + (n-2) + n(n-3) + ...   +   3    +   2  + 1`

Now *merge* those two sequences and rearrange the summands intelligently and set some parenthesis.

`[n + 1] + [(n-1) + 2] + [(n-2) + 3] + [(n-3) + 4] + ... =`

We still have `n` summands, each of them is `(n + 1)`
but as we've just written the same numbers twice we need to divide
our result by `2`.

`(n + 1) +   (n + 1)   +   (n + 1)   +   (n + 1)   + ... = n (n+1) /2`

### Mathematical proof using induction

Given the hypothesis `n (n+1) /2` it's not hard to proof via induction that this is in fact true. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Sum_of_consecutive_natural_numbers).

Comment: Brillant! Thanks.

Comment: Do you think you can help me on the other thread? Appreciate much. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71811336/difficulty-understanding-the-tree-traversal-analysis-of-height1-of-on2-in-d