# Difficulty understanding the tree traversal analysis of height1() of O(n^2) in Data Structure and Algorithms in C++ Michael T. Goodrich 2nd ED

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, big-o

I will try my best summarising and explain as best as i can here. This is about tree traversal algorithms.

A) Class Position

```
template <typename E> // base element type
class Position<E> { // a node position
public:
    E& operator*(); // get element
    Position parent() const; // get parent
    PositionList children() const; // get node’s children
    bool isRoot() const; // root node?
    bool isExternal() const; // external node?
};
```

B) Class Tree

```
template <typename E> // base element type
class Tree<E> {
public: // public types
    class Position; // a node position
    class PositionList; // a list of positions
public: // public functions
    int size() const; // number of nodes
    bool empty() const; // is tree empty?
    Position root() const; // get the root
    PositionList positions() const; // get positions of all nodes. According to author, PositionList is implemented as list<Position>. There's no definition for PositionList nor is there implementation for positions() function shown. Left as an exercise.
};
```

According to author, the depth() & height1() of a tree can be implemented as below.

```
int depth(const Tree& T, const Position& p) {    
     if (p.isRoot()) return 0; // root has depth 0     
     else return 1 + depth(T, p.parent());     
}    

int height1(const Tree& T) {
    int h = 0;
    PositionList nodes = T.positions(); // list of all nodes
    for (Iterator q = nodes.begin(); q != nodes.end(); ++q) {
       if (q−>isExternal())
          h = max(h, depth(T, *q)); // get max depth among leaves
    }
    return h;
}
```

Author's excerpt:

> Unfortunately, algorithm height1 is not very efficient. Since height1 calls algorithm depth(p) on each external node p of T , the running time of height1 is given
> by O(n+∑p(1+dp)), where n is the number of nodes of T , dp is the depth of node
> p, and E is the set of external nodes of T . In the worst case, the sum ∑p(1 + dp)
> is proportional to n^2.

why n^2 (quadratic)?

I tried couple of samples as shown below:

[image]

I tried N=5,6,7,8 and it still doesn't come up to n^2.

Any help here be great.
Thanks.

Comment: Why is this voted down?

Comment: I guess because you just asked [an identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71811063/difficulty-understanding-the-tree-traversal-analysis-of-positions-of-on-in-d). Delete this one.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Tx. Typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the worst case, the sum ∑p(1 + dp) is proportional to n^2

It should be simpler to understand with a "worst case" scenario. Consider a "[skewed](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/skewed-binary-tree/)" subtree with `n/2` nodes arranged linearly, and the last node has `n/2` children (which will be the leaf or "external" nodes in this case). The tree would look something like

```
1
 \
  2
  ...
    \
     n/2
 ______|________
|  |  |  |  |  |
(remaining n/2 nodes)
```

For each external node, we have the depth as `n/2`, so calculating it takes `O(n/2) ~ O(n)` time. And since there are `n/2` nodes for which depth gets calculated, the complexity becomes `O(n/2 * n/2) ~ O(n^2)`, which is the worst case complexity mentioned by the author.

##### Edit:

Here's an illustration of the aforementioned tree for `n=10`. You can see why each external node would require a `O(n/2) ~ O(n)` traversal:

[image: sample worst case tree]

Comment: if the worst case scenario is a skew tree then it should only have 1 leaf. A skew tree has only 1 external node, similar to the bottom right tree on my diagram. So height1() will only call once (if (q−>isExternal()) and if n=3 the depth() will recursivelly traverse 3 times. So i don't get it.

Comment: Your diagram has many leafs. So how can that be a skew tree?

Comment: @yapkm01 the entire tree isn't skewed, only the first `n/2` nodes are. Anyways, clarified that in the answer. The rest still holds up correctly

Comment: Thanks. Let me digest it. I still have hard time understanding it now. Appreciate.

Comment: I think for a start, can you use number like n=10 and redraw the tree. Don't use n/2. I need to see an actual number like n=10 showing exactly how that tree would look like on a worst case scenario. Then maybe i can see the light .. :OP

Comment: @yapkm01 added the sample tree

Comment: Got it! One last question. The most difficult part is finding the tree configuration which has the worst case scenario? Your diagram has 5 external nodes representing worst case scenario.  There could be other layout as well. This is is one of my biggest struggle when comes to analysis. How do i find out the worst case scenario? Is there a rule of thumb on this?

Comment: @yapkm01 I'm not sure if there's a rule of thumb, but from observation, if `x+y = constant`, then `x*y` will be maximum when `x=y`. That's why I've kept `number of external nodes = max depth of each external node = n/2`

Comment: Thanks a lot. :O)